# How can I get back access to the backend of TYPO3 when fluidpages are causing an error on backend and frontend?

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I got to work on a Typo3 page and I have to say I'm at the very beginning if it comes to TYPO3.

So I wanted to fix a bug and updated the plugin "fluidpages" from version 4.1.0 (I guess) to 4.3. That cause the "Oops, an error occurred!" in the backend and frontend, so I dont have access from that side. I still have the FTP login for the website. The version of TYPO3 is 8.7.18.

The errorcode I get is that one:

> Could not analyse class:
>   "FluidTYPO3\Flux\Configuration\ConfigurationManager" maybe not loaded
>   or no autoloader?
>   Class FluidTYPO3\Flux\Configuration\ConfigurationManager does not exist

So does anyone know what I need to do?
From my research I think I need to update another plugins to make it back to work? And can I update them just by uploading them through FTP?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: After I tried to get the old version of the plugin running, I'm getting this error code from the log file:

> Mon, 17 Feb 2020 22:59:56 +0100 [ALERT] request="fec23f8baf6dc" component="TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.ContentObject.Exception.ProductionExceptionHandler": Oops, an error occurred! Code: 2020021722595594039a4d - {"exception":"TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception: The default controller for extension \"Flux\" and plugin \"Page\" can not be determined. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the [Install Tool](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/8.7/en-us/In-depth/TheInstallTool/Index.html#the-install-tool-in-depth) via https://example.org/typo3/install.php and start with *Check for broken extensions*. If that doesn't yield the extension in question, you can always manually change the [`PackageStates.php` file](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-inside/8.7/en-us/CoreArchitecture/Extensions/Index.html#package-manager) and remove the extension you want to unload. Afterwards you should flush all caches through the Install Tool.

In the long term you should consider a few things:

1. Use a local development environment which mirrors your production environment. You can safely perform all steps without any risk here before deploying.
2. Use a deployment strategy/tool which allows for rollbacks. This allows you to quickly revert to a working version of your instance in case all other checks have failed. A simple but flexible solution is [Deployer](https://deployer.org/), you'll need SSH for this though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, "sadly" all extensions can be loaded. Just the error about the 
 ConfigurationManager disappeared. The Oops is still there.
I don't want to remove the extension, because it's necessary to build the content of the page as far as I can say. I thought I could downgrade the one plugin maybe.

Yes you are right, I didn't think so far in that case, well I thought it won't destroy the site when I update one plugin. Thanks for the mentioned tool.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dumping autoload from Install Tool? Generally, it would help for the class not loaded problem. Otherwise, you may want to check the log at typo3/temp/var/log/ and find the errors in code.

Comment: Yes, I did that too. I edited the first posting with a new error code I found in the log.