# How can I restore my site from Error 500 in Typo3?

Tags: typo3

I am a newbie in Typo3 platform. I was working on installing some extensions. But all of a sudden I am getting I am getting error 500 and can't access backend too.

How can I sort this problem?

Thanks
Prasun

Comment: Please see my answer on [How can I get back access to the backend of TYPO3 when fluidpages are causing an error on backend and frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60267334/6812729)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did try what was recommended before and nothing works, you can Delete the temp folder and if still no success it helps if you switch PHP from FASTCGI to Standart and if you can login, set it back.